# How to define a non-swipeable area in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile

[image: Screenshot]
I would like to activate the "swiperight" function only for the area marked in green.
I it possible to define a non-swipeable area?

Comment: Is this a panel? Post the code where you are handling the swipe, please.

Comment: Yes, it is a panel with id "myPanel". Here is the code:

$(function () {
    $('body').on('swiperight', function () {
        $('#myPanel').panel('open', '');
    });

    $('body').on('swipeleft', function () {
        $('#myPanel').panel('close');
    });
});

Comment: We need to know what kind of panel, and which version of the library. Please complete Your question and post some code (and related markup) inside Your answer.

Comment: I'm really sorry. It is about the left panel. Here an example: [http://plnkr.co/edit/iYfuYk1gxTtWtEOq?open=lib%2Fscript.js]

Comment: You have in Your example the "*Pure CSS solution for panel always open at large screens*". Is this related to Your question? Maybe just guessing, You want to avoid the built-in JavaScript panel opening when the panel `visibility` is already set to `visible`? By using the *Pure CSS* solution You will lose the panel events and You will end-up to have such kind of side-effects.

Comment: The "Pure CSS solution for panels always open on large screens" is intended. If the screen is smaller than 1024px, the panel is hidden and can be displayed with the burger menu or with the Swiperight function. My problem: I want to limit the area in which the Swiperight function is active to the first few centimeters. Swiperight function should be deactivated in the area marked in red and only work in the area marked in green (see screenshot above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more than one possible solution, to achieve what You asked for.

The `swipe`, `swipeleft` and `swiperight` are custom jQuery Mobile events. JQM is attaching to these events a custom structure which contain the start and stop coordinates of the original touch events.

First of all, if You want to handle the swipe by yourself, You need to tell this to the framework:

**Skip the built-in panel swipe handler:**

```
<div data-role="panel" id="myPanel" data-swipe-close="false">
```

After that, to open or close the `panel`, You can simply check either the coordinates of the `touchstart`, `touchend` or both (up to You to decide this).

**Custom handling of the touch events:**

```
$('body').on('swiperight', function (e) {
  var startX = e.swipestart.coords[0],
    stopX = e.swipestop.coords[0];   
  if(startX < 100) {
    $('#myPanel').panel('open');
  } 
});

$('body').on('swipeleft', function (e) {
  var startX = e.swipestart.coords[0],
    stopX = e.swipestop.coords[0];   
  if(stopX < 100) {    
    $('#myPanel').panel('close');
  } 
});
```

If You want a more systematic approach, You may also check the some of the relevant `panel` options:

```
var data = $('#myPanel').data("mobile-panel"),
    display = data.options.display, /* Panel Type: reveal, push, overlay */
    position = data.options.position; /* Panel position: left, right */
```

and fine-tune the swipe actions (or whatever You want) accordingly.